# How to design a program that does not make parallel arrays

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am working on an assignment in my Java textbook that says:

> Modify the GradeRange program (Listing 6.5) from this chapter so that it doesn't use parallel arrays. Instead, design a new class called Grade that stores both the grade string and its cutoff value (the lowest score for that grade). Set both values using the Grade constructor and provide methods that return the values. In the main method of the new GradeRange program, fill a single array with Grade objects, and then produce the same output as the original GradeRange program did.

Here is the GradeRange program:

```
//********************************************************************
//  GradeRange.java       Author: Lewis/Loftus/Cocking
//
//  Demonstrates the use of an array of String objects.
//********************************************************************

public class GradeRange
{
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------
   //  Stores the possible grades and their numeric lowest value,
   //  then prints them out.
   //-----------------------------------------------------------------



 public static void main (String[] args)
   {
  String[] grades = {"A", "A-", "B+", "B", "B-", "C+", "C", "C-",
                     "D+", "D", "D-", "F"};

  int[] cutoff = {95, 90, 87, 83, 80, 77, 73, 70, 67, 63, 60, 0};

  for (int level = 0; level < cutoff.length; level++)
     System.out.println (grades[level] + "\t" + cutoff[level]);


}
}
```

I don't understand in the question when it says:

> ...stores both the grade string and its cutoff value... Set both values using the Grade constructor...

Here is my start of the class:

```
public class Grade
{
public Grade (String[] grades, int[] cutoff)
{
```

I don't know how I would store the grade string and cutoff into the constructor if that is what the assignment is asking. I also don't know what an array that is not parallel would look like. I guess my final questions is how would I develop the program (what methods to make...)? And what is the question asking when it says

> fill a single array with Grade objects

OUTPUT:

```
A   95
A-  90
B+  87
B   83
B-  80
C+  77
C   73
C-  70
D+  67
D   63
D-  60
F   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're meant to create a list of Grade objects instead of keeping two arrays to store the grade and the cutoffs. You can do so like:

```
public class Grade{
  //Replace these two with getters and setters if you know what they are
  public String grade;
  public int cutoff;

  public Grade(String gradeConstructorArg, int cutoffConstructorArg){
    this.grade = gradeConstructorArg;
    this.cutoff = cutoffConstructorArg;
  }
}
```

And then just make an array of Grades in the main method like:

```
 public static void main (String[] args){
  Grade[] grades = {new Grade("A", 95), new Grade("A-", 90)}; //Add more

  for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
     System.out.println (grades[i].grade + "\t" + grades[i].cutoff);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, however, when I am adding to the Grade array, would the code look like this? `Grade[] grades = {new Grade("A", 95), new Grade("A-", 90), new Grade("B+", 87), new Grade("B", 83) new Grade("B-", 80) new Grade("C+", 77) new Grade("C", 73) new Grade("C-", 70) new Grade(D+-", 67) new Grade("D", 63) new Grade("D-", 60) new Grade("F", 0)};`                                                                                                                    When I compile, it says '}' expected  and it highlights after the fourth new Grade

Comment: @Nub Looks like you're missing the commas for every grade after the `new Grade("B", 83)` entry

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry that I didn't catch that very simple mistake.

Comment: when I get the output for that code, I think it still outputs like a parallel array.  I still don't understand what I need to do to change the format of the array to make it not parallel. I edited my original post to show the output. the code u gave me lhas the same output as the code in the book.

Comment: @Nub what do you mean by "parallel"? How do you expect it to print?

Comment: @ Mr D well when the assignment talks about parallel arrays I was thinking of the output of the array in which I have no idea what a non parallel array would look like. However, now I know that It is referring to the array as code.

Comment: @Nub well before you were storing the grades and the cutoff as two separate arrays, now you have 1 single class Grade that stores both, and a single array that stores each grade. Effectively they both do the same thing but now the code is much cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 3):

Your `Grade` class as shown looks like it is still going to contain two parallel arrays, but just hide them.

What is being asked for is a class like

```
class Grade
{
     // TODO add all the correct constructors, getters and setters
     private String grade;
     private int cutoff;
}
```

You then need to create and store an array of `Grade` instances.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that the question is also requiring that you create getter methods for your Grade class to get the values of grade and cutoff. The implication is that you should declare grade and cutoff as private within the class and use the public getter methods to retrieve:

```
public class Grade{

    private String grade;
    private int cutoff;

    public Grade(String grade, int cutoff){
        this.grade = grade;
        this.cutoff = cutoff;
    }

    public String getGrade(){
         return grade;
    }

    public int getCutoff(){
         return cutoff;
    }
}
```

Then be sure to retrieve them as Mr D referenced, but modify the output routine as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
    System.out.println(grades[i].getGrade() + "\t" + grades[i].getCutoff());
```

Comment: ok thank you very much, I think i was just confused with my assignment question but what would the output look like?

Comment: The output would look just like what you have in your original post.

Comment: I think you're confusing the format of the output with the structure of the single array containing objects. Each object within the single array contains the grade and cutoff values. You can format the output of an array of objects any way you want. The point is that the assignment wants you to create Grade objects you can put in 1 array vs. using 2 arrays that depend on corresponding grades and cutoff values.

Comment: Ok I get it now. I think I'm over thinking everything. Thank you very much for everyone's help